# Плавная анимация Free Pascal с модулем Graph

Tags: анимация, freepascal

Анимация мерцает в графике. В Pascal ABC было `LockDrawing` и `RedRaw`, они сначала отрисовывали в памяти картинку, затем выводили готовый результат на экран без мерцания, в Free Pascal мерцает даже с `delay(10);`.
Вот пример, кружок мерцает, хоть не сильно, но это больше добился из-за `delay(10)`:

```
uses graph,wincrt;

Var
  gm,gd: smallint;
  x,y,R2,i,R1: Word;

Begin
  gm := 0;
  gd := detect;
  InitGraph(gd, gm, ' ');

  R2 := 150;
  R1 := 20;

  repeat
    if i < 360 then inc(i) else i := 0;
    x := Round(getmaxx div 2 + R2 * cos(2*Pi/360*i));
    y := Round(getmaxy div 2 + R2 * sin(2*Pi/360*i));
    circle(x,y,R1);
    delay(10);
    ClearDevice;
  until keypressed;

  CloseGraph;
End.
```

Посмотрите без delay(10) и с ним, разница есть, но все равно не идеал, можно ли добиться идеальной анимации без мерцания?
Код с `SetActivePage/SetVisualPage`:

```
uses graph,wincrt;

Var
  gm,gd: smallint;
  x,y,R2,i,R1,a: Word;

Begin
  gm := 0;
  gd := detect;
  InitGraph(gd, gm, ' ');

  R2 := 150;
  R1 := 20;
  a := 0;
  repeat
    SetActivePage(a);
    ClearDevice;
    if i < 360 then inc(i) else i := 0;
    x := Round(getmaxx div 2 + R2 * cos(2*Pi/360*i));
    y := Round(getmaxy div 2 + R2 * sin(2*Pi/360*i));
    circle(x,y,R1);
    SetVisualPage(a);
    if a = 1 then a := 0 else a := 1;
  until keypressed;

  CloseGraph;
End.
```

Comment: Начните с публикации своего кода и конкретного вопроса.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov знаете как помочь? Код добавил.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть на процедуры `SetActivePage`/`SetVisualPage`. А вообще вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/free-pascal/thread1922650.html Как решите проблему - напишите сюда ответ

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не заметил изменений, код добавил новый. Хотел еще узнать, в чем разница WinGraph и Graph? Мне сказали разницы нет, можно любой использовать, они совместимы.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я поставил WinGraph, мерцаний куда меньше, а можно вообще без мерцания?

Comment: Так видеостраницы используйте. На одной рисуете, вторую показываете

Comment: @AntonShchyrov в free pascal есть возможность отслеживать нажатие и отпускание клавиш? В GraphABC я делал `onkeydown/onkeyup`, тут такого нет.

Comment: Почему бы не задать новый вопрос?